# Ram in laptop with same brand but different part numbers?

Tags: laptop, memory

I'm having a Lenovo Laptop ( Lenovo Ideapad gaming 3) with 8GB ram capacity. So, I want to upgrade my laptop on Ram and SSD. My memory's information is Kingston 8GB DDR4 bus 3200mhz with part number LV32D4S2S8HD-8.

My question is:

Is it good for my laptop if I use another Ram with different part number to the old one? The one I found on some shops around me has the part number: KVR32S22S8/8.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 3600MHZ RAM enough or 3200MHZ?](https://superuser.com/questions/1742021/is-3600mhz-ram-enough-or-3200mhz)

Comment: Even better: [Relationship between CPU and Memory Clock Speeds](https://superuser.com/questions/1670031/relationship-between-cpu-and-memory-clock-speeds/1670045#1670045)

Answer (score 2):

Your RAMs are :

- Existing : LV32D4S2S8HD-8 Kingston 8GB PC4-25600 DDR4-3200MHz non-ECC Unbuffered CL22 260-Pin SoDimm 1.2V Single Rank Memory Module
- New : KVR32S22S8/8 Kingston 8GB PC4-25600 DDR4-3200MHz non-ECC Unbuffered CL22 260-Pin SoDimm 1.2V Single Rank Memory Module

The specs are identical, so there is an excellent chance that the new RAM
will work together with the old one.

However, there are no certainties where RAM and motherboard compatibility
is concerned. In addition to these characteristics, there are many more
that are not published. I would suggest to ensure that whatever vendor
you buy from has a very good no-questions-asked return policy.

For more information see the post
[What exactly is the cause of RAM incompatibility?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250578/what-exactly-is-the-cause-of-ram-incompatibility)